# Adding a character to existing string

Tags: string, postgresql, insert, sql-update, substring

Sorry if I missed a possible solution to my problem, but I need some pointers. I'm sure there is an easy solution, but I'm not seeing it (currently).

So I have a Postgres DB table which needs mass update, just adding a single character at a specific position in the string.

example:

`select PINFO.title, SUBSTRING(PINFO.title FROM ',\ (.+). del') AS ep_num from my_table where my_condition...`

so i get something like that:

```
+--------------------+--------+
|       title        | ep_num |
+--------------------+--------+
| my_series, 01. del |     01 |
| my_series, 10. del |     10 |
| my_series, 11. del |     11 |
| my_series, 2. del  |      2 |
| my_series, 3. del  |      3 |
| my_series, 4. del  |      4 |
| my_series, 5. del  |      5 |
| my_series, 6. del  |      6 |
| my_series, 7. del  |      7 |
| my_series, 8. del  |      8 |
| my_series, 9. del  |      9 |
+--------------------+--------+
```

So what would I like is to add a 0 where there is a number lower than 10. So my expected result should be:

```
+--------------------+--------+
|       title        | ep_num |
+--------------------+--------+
| my_series, 01. del |     01 |
| my_series, 10. del |     10 |
| my_series, 11. del |     11 |
| my_series, 02. del |     02 |
| my_series, 03. del |     03 |
| my_series, 04. del |     04 |
| my_series, 05. del |     05 |
| my_series, 06. del |     06 |
| my_series, 07. del |     07 |
| my_series, 08. del |     08 |
| my_series, 09. del |     09 |
+--------------------+--------+
```

What would be the best approach? I need to update the table, not just print the output this way.
Thank you!
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=802025b2b161627319f4bc2fe37e3fae)

```
UPDATE my_table
SET 
    title = 'my_series, ' || lpad(ep_num, 2, '0') || '. del',
    ep_num = lpad(ep_num, 2, '0')
```

Use the [`lpad()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function

---

**Without `ep_num` column**:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8fc609b6112e223504e59cf47fbb66af)

```
UPDATE my_table mt
SET title = parts[1] || ' ' || lpad(parts[2], 3, '0') || ' ' || parts[3]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        title,
        regexp_split_to_array(title, ' ') AS parts
    FROM
        my_table
) s
WHERE mt.title = s.title
```

`regexp_split_to_table()` splits the title at the spaces into three parts.
They can be merged again after left padding the second piece. The `lpad()` function here creates a 3 character long text instead of 2 because the splitting before also concerns the dot.

Comment: Ignore the ep_num column as it's just extra displayed for easier overview and sorting. The error is "ERROR:  column "ep_num" does not exist".